# How to show data from Access in the correct order?

Tags: ms-access, netbeans, jtable, ucanaccess

```
String sql="select ID,Hmerominia,Agores,Pliromes,Eksoda,Zhta,Metaforika,Pliromimetafo,Epitages,Xondriki,Noiki,Plirominoiki  from  Synola";

 try{
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
   jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

   // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved");

}catch(Exception ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);

}
```

Read from database is fixed now but the ID which is 1 to 312 the numbers on the jtable don't come in order as in database.How can i fix this?

Comment: *"If in the line i add rs=pst.executeQuery(sql); The error is feature not supported."* - Yes, of course. That is not how you use a PreparedStatement. However, `pst.executeQuery();` should work correctly.

Comment: the program freezes  with pst.executeQuery();

Comment: Try opening the database with "console.bat" or "console.sh" from the UCanAccess distribution. If the database opens successfully then try `SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM Synola;` and see if that returns the correct row count.

Comment: it show in the jtable n and 1 blank row.I do not see the already insered data from database.

Comment: No, I meant running that `SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM Synola;` query from "console.bat" or "console.sh" via an OS command prompt. The idea is to determine if your issue has more to do with UCanAccess or more to do with getting the information into your jTable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the current state of your code and how it (now) fails to meet your expectations. (Don't bury significant additional details in the comments where people might not see them.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the ID which is 1 to 312 the numbers on the jtable don't come in order

The only way to guarantee the order in which rows are returned by a SQL statement is to include an ORDER BY clause. In your case you need to add `ORDER BY ID` to the end of your SQL statement.